# Convert Objective-C to Swift to Mock S3

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to mock S3, but I seem unable to come up with the Swift equivalent of the following:

```
- (void)listObjects:(AWSS3ListObjectsRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^ _Nullable)(AWSS3ListObjectsOutput * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

I've tried quite a few alternatives:

```
//    func listObjects(request: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest) -> AWSTask<AWSS3ListObjectsOutput>
//    func listObjects(request: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest, completionHandler: (AWSTask<AWSS3ListObjectsOutput>) -> AnyObject?)
    func listObjects(request: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest, completionHandler: () -> AWSTask<AWSS3ListObjectsOutput>)
//    - (void)listObjects:(AWSS3ListObjectsRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^ _Nullable)(AWSS3ListObjectsOutput * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

ButI can't seem to get one that AWSS3 conforms to. I need to do this to mock the function in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func listObjects(request: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest, completionHandler: ((AWSS3ListObjectsOutput?, Error?) -> Void)?) {

}
```